# Why cf.go_offline doesn't work in pyCharm

Tags: python, plotly, offline

I am trying to create plots using cufflinks in pycharm. I am going offline as suggested in the previous posts, but I don't have any influence and it seem like the program is skipping the command.

I tried to downgrade plotly but it didn't work and higher version of plotly (4) is not compatible with cufflinks.

```
import cufflinks as cf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly import __version__
from plotly.offline import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()


df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,4),columns='A B C D'.split())
df.iplot()
plt.show()

# The error I am getting is:

Aw, snap! We didn't get a username with your request.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/Maciek_pc/Documents/studies/programming/ML/cufflinks/cufflinks1.py", line 21, in <module>
Don't have an account? https://plot.ly/api_signup
    df.iplot()

Questions? accounts@plot.ly
  File "C:\Users\Maciek_pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cufflinks\plotlytools.py", line 1216, in _iplot
    dimensions=dimensions,display_image=kwargs.get('display_image',True))
  File "C:\Users\Maciek_pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cufflinks\plotlytools.py", line 1462, in iplot
    filename=filename)
```

Comment: There's currently an [open GitHub issue](https://github.com/santosjorge/cufflinks/issues/196) on the `cufflinks` repo about this incompatibility with `plotly` v4. From what I can tell there's currently no solution for this if you want offline plotting. If you're okay with online you can use the fix in [this issue](https://github.com/santosjorge/cufflinks/issues/185) to use `chart_studio` instead. Maybe your best bet is to try and downgrade to an earlier version of Plotly. Can you describe how the downgrade is failing in your case?

Comment: hi, I tried alreaady downgrading, didn't work out. The only solution I found is actually go online and just view the plots on your account on plotly website. Of course, it doesn't work when you arent connected to the internet :/

Comment: What I mean is why is downgrading not working for you? Is that not a viable solution that you'd like help with? If downgrading is not an option then I'm afraid you'll have to wait for the next release to have it fixed.

Comment: @Maciek Woźniak Are you able to produce other plotly figures that do not rely on `iplot()`?

Comment: @vestland Yes, just iplot() is not working.

Comment: @Mihai, I don't know why it is not working, however, when I downgrade the plotly, the errors dont appear, but neither the graph.